# How do I build a grand-child record using the build_ helper method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my `user.rb` file, after the user is created, I then create a Profile for the User with the following helper method:

```
profile = user.profile.build(profile_params)
profile.save
```

And after that I want to create a Position child record of the Profile, but it seems the build methods don't work for grand children. Here's my code:

```
position = profile.build_position(position_params)
position.save
```

I get this error:

> undefined method `build_position' for #

What am I doing wrong? I've triple checked all my associations. They are setup properly. `User has_one Profile`, and `Profile belongs_to User`. `Profile has_many Positions`, and `Position belongs_to Profile`.

User > Profile > Positions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a `has_many` association, use `association.build`

ex.

```
position = profile.positions.build(position_params)
```